# Is a continuous map from a connected set to the natural numbers constant?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am given that $(X,d)$ is a metric space and $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is a continuous function. I want to show that if $X$ is connected, then $f$ is constant.

My proof goes as follows:

Suppose, as a contradiction, that $f(X)$ is not constant, then it is an interval $(a,b)$ containing only natural numbers. Take any two natural numbers $f(x_1), f(x_2) \in (a,b)$ and such that $f(x_1) \neq f(x_2)$. Then, since $f$ is continuous, that implies that for any $\epsilon >0$, there exists a $\delta$ such that $d_x(x_1,x_2)<\delta$ implies $d_{\mathbb{N}}(f(x_1),f_(x_2))< \epsilon$. But, if we let $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$, the only way that $d_{\mathbb{N}}(f(x_1),f_(x_2))< \epsilon$ is to find a $\delta$ such that we have $d_{\mathbb{N}}(f(x_1),f_(x_2))=0$ but for such $\delta$ this would imply that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ which is contradiction, since we assumed $f(x_1) \neq f(x_2)$. Thus is must be that $f(X)$ is a constant.

Is this prove right? I am trying to exploit the fact that $f$ is continuous and if $f(X)$ is not constant then it would be an interval that is not continuous, since no interval in $\mathbb{N}$ is continuous.

Comment: Have you seen the proof that the image of a connected space under a continuous map is connected?

Comment: No, I that comes in the next section in my book.

Comment: The start of your proof is somewhat shaky. Also if $f$ is constant then $f(X)$ can be described as $(a,b)\cap\mathbb N$. Btw, intervals are not essential here. You can just start with the assumption that $x,y\in X$ exist with $f(x)\neq f(y)$ followed by the abduction of a contradiction. A short look at that next section can be enlightening.

Comment: The statement is true, but I don't think your proof is correct. It's not clear where you're using the assumption that $X$ is connected, which is definitely needed.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes.

Since $f$ is continuous and $X$ is connected, then the image of $f$ must be connected, but the only connected sets in a discrete space are singletons. Hence the image of $f$ must be mapped to a single element.

Answer (score 1):

Since you say that $f$ is continuous, you must also specify a topology on $\Bbb N$; I shall assume that you use the discrete topology. This means that $\{ n \}$ is open $\forall n$. Note that $X = \bigcup \limits _{n \in \Bbb N} f^{-1} (\{ n \})$; these subsets are disjoint. Assume that there exist at least two non-empty among them; this implies that $X$ is not connected, because a connected set cannot be written as a union of disjoint open subsets. Therefore, only one of the sets $f^{-1} (\{ n \})$ can be non-empty, so $f$ is constant (and equal to this $n$).